# Google app engine Python issue

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I developed app using html5 and php. Since php is not yet fully supported on google app engine I would like to change my php code to python because I have 8 lines of php code. Problem is, I'm total noob with python. I'm used to make index.html and that run fine with php, but when I try to run index.html with python then I get blank page. Can someone explain how to run html5 document with python on google app engine.
This is what I tried:

```
html = """

 here goes my site

""";

import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render(html);

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the tutorial, specifically where it covers templates? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates

Answer (score 2):

I checked the GAE python start tutorial. Maybe your code

```
self.render(html);
```

should be:

```
self.response.write("Hello world!");
```

I don't think the class webapp2.RequestHandler has the **render** function, because I've tried your code on [GAE's cloud play ground](https://cloud-playground.appspot.com/playground/p/5796738044526592/#helloworld.py), it raises an error:

> AttributeError: 'MainHandler' object has no attribute 'render'

And if you want to render a template, it should be used like this:

```
......
template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

Documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates)

Comment: I made folder 'template' and placed index.html into it, then I made the following: import webapp2

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname('template')),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'])

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        
 template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html');
 self.response.write(template.render(template_values));

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
and it's still not working

Comment: Never add code in your comments, update your opening post with new code and complete error please